# complex analysis $\int _{\left|z + 1\right|=4}^{ }\:\frac{5+3z}{-z^3 + 4z}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm having trouble to solve this question
$$\int _{\left|z + 1\right|=4}^{ }\:\frac{5+3z}{-z^3 + 4z}dz$$
I already tried $w = z + 1$ but couldn't find the answer that is zero.
I also understand that we have $z=0$, $z=2$ and $z=-2$ as singularities but I couldn't find a way to use them with residue theorem.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: All three singularities are enclosed in a circular contour with radius $4$ about $z=-1$. If this contour is made to be counterclockwise, then your contour integral is equal to $2\pi i$ times the sum of the residues of those three simple poles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $-z^3+4z=-z(z+2)(z-2)$, your integrand function has simple poles $z_1=0$, $z_2=-2$ and $z_3=2$. All of them belongs to the interior of the circle of center $(-1,0)$ and radius $4$, hence for the Cauchy theorem your integral $I$ is
$$-I=-2\pi i\left[\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{5+3z}{(z+2)(z-2)}+\lim_{z \to 2} \frac{5+3z}{z(z+2)}+\lim_{z \to -2} \frac{5+3z}{z(z-2)}\right]=0$$

Comment: thanks! I committed a typo trying to solve this question using exactly this!

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options.

Option 1 (least elegant) is to just parameterize your curve as $\gamma(t) = -1+4e^{it}$ and apply the definition of the integral.  You should get an integral you can do with "calc 1" techniques.

Option 2 (somewhat more elegant) is to use partial fraction decomposition to rewrite your integrand in the form $\frac{A}{z} + \frac{B}{z-2} + \frac{C}{z+2}$ for some complex numbers $A, B, C$.  Then split up the integral using linearity of the integral and apply Cauchy's integral formula to each one.

Option 3 (most elegant?) is to realize that the you can replace the curve you are integrating over with one circle around each pole.  Then write the integrals in the form

$$
\int_{C_0} \frac{\frac{5+3z}{4-z^2}}{z} \textrm{ d}z + \int_{C_{-2}} \frac{\frac{5+3z}{z(2-z)}}{2+z} \textrm{ d}z
+ \int_{C_2} \frac{\frac{5+3z}{z(2+z)}}{2-z} \textrm{ d}z$$

Then evaluate each integral using Cauchy's integral formula.  For this you do not even need partial fraction decomposition!

Option 4 (biggest hammer?) Calculate the residues at $0$, $2$, and $-2$.  This is a rational function, so you should be able to find a Laurent expansion about each pole just by cleverly manipulating the formula for a geometric series.  Once you have the residues, apply the residue theorem.

Methods 2, 3, and 4 all end up really amounting to the same thing, but they are slightly different perspectives on the calculation.